# std::atomic on a simple POD class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have read many articles and questions on that, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885617/how-to-use-stdatomic-effectively-for-non-primitive-types), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739306/stdatomic-trivially-copyable-structs), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886308/stdatomic-with-custom-class-c-11), and all the answers provided are inconclusive as to what should actually be done in such a situation:

Currently I am writing a concurrent program where I need to concurrently access the size and top of a `std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>>` many times, while pushing and popping elements elsewhere.
But it would be too inefficient to lock the `mutex` every time a read is needed (and a solution to readers and writers problem is not efficient enough either).

The only thing that is good enough is to wrap those three attributes in a `std::atomic` and update the atomic on every update of the queue, which would work, if only the compiler allowed me to do that.

Sadly, g++ 7.2.0 outputs the

> "undefined reference to '__atomic_load'"

error message while linking.

I tried adding `-latomic` to the `CMakeLists.txt`, but I got

> "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latomic"

error instead (and I am not allowed to change or update the compiler).

My struct is a POD type (I checked that with `static_assert`), so I just don't get why does it not work. How can I get it to work?

EDIT: I compiled almost the same code as the one in the third link,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

struct Vec {
    int x, y, z;
};
int main() {
    std::atomic<Vec> x;
    Vec a;
    x = a;
}
```

and got the following error message

```
CMakeFiles/folder.dir/vec.cpp.o: In function `std::atomic<Vec>::store(Vec, std::memory_order)':
vec.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6atomicI3VecE5storeES0_St12memory_order[_ZNSt6atomicI3VecE5storeES0_St12memory_order]+0x47): undefined reference to `__atomic_store'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It's worth noting that if you create an `atomic<T>` where T is not supported directly by the underlying hardware (which generally means that it's not a plain integer of the native platform size or smaller), essentially all it does is to wrap all the accessors with a mutex, so I'm not sure it will gain something over just duplicating the data and using a plain mutex.

Comment: Even when it works, on hardware not having 12 bytes atomic instructions, the implementation is likely to use some kind of mutex anyway.

Comment: Btw, based on your description, I don't believe you need the strong reordering guarantee provided by the default [std::memory_order::seq_cst](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) that `atomic` uses. Since the variable is not guarding access to other memory or similar, I think that all you need is [std::memory_order_relaxed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering) in this case.

Comment: [Reading around](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65756) it does seem that you should link against `libatomic`; if that is missing from your system, that's the thing you should fix. But again, I wouldn't waste much time over `std::atomic<T>` - it's important to access atomic primitives on types that support them, but for bigger stuff it's just a mutex. If even `std::mutex` turns out to be too heavyweight, you can implement a plain spinlock (given that you are probably going to access this thing very quickly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving/expaning from a comment:

g++ `std::atomic<T>` implementation [requires libatomic for non-natively supported types](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65756#c1).

I can reproduce and fix your error with `-latomic` indeed:

```
[matteo@teolapkubuntu /tmp]$ g++ -O3 test.cpp
/tmp/cc7YRyMy.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3f): undefined reference to `__atomic_store'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[matteo@teolapkubuntu /tmp]$ g++ -O3 test.cpp -latomic
[matteo@teolapkubuntu /tmp]$
```

Still, if your toolchain doesn't provide libatomic I wouldn't worry too much.

Atomic stores for non-natively supported types in libatomic boil down to [either a compare-exchange loop](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_2_0-release/libatomic/gstore.c#L94) (see the [`LARGER` macro](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_2_0-release/libatomic/gstore.c#L70)), or, in the "degenerate" cases (`T` bigger than 16 bytes), [to a plain mutex](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_2_0-release/libatomic/gstore.c#L100) ([`libat_lock_n`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-7_2_0-release/libatomic/config/posix/lock.c#L80) uses a hash of the target address and locks the corresponding locks from some global pool of locks).

This is all stuff that you can implement yourself without much hassle - actually, you are in a better position than the writers of *libatomic*, as you can add extra data members instead of having to exploit the target data itself or its address from a lock pool.

First of all, I'd try with a plain mutex protecting your separate copy of the data. Given that this mutex should be taken for an extremely short time, I don't expect much contention; given that you have one writer and multiple readers, you may experiment with [std::shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) if your compiler is recent enough.

If the plain mutex turns out to be too slow, you can [fall back to a spinlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195378/214671); again, since it should be taken for an extremely short time, it should be perfectly fine for your use case. If you need even more speed, you'll have to get your hands dirty [with extra tricks](https://locklessinc.com/articles/locks/) (possibly using optimized RW spinlocks).